# Blank Polygon issue using QGIS Contour Plugin

Tags: qgis, contour

I am using QGIS with Contour plugin, want to generate filled contour polygons with user selected contour levels.

However there are some errors showing blank polygons.

Is it bug or is there any way to fix it?

Parameter is here

```
{ 'ContourInterval' : 1, 'ContourLevels' : '0.0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0 1.5 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6 7 8 9 10 12 14 16 18 20 25 30 35 40 50 60 70 80 90 100', 'ContourMethod' : 4, 'ContourType' : 1, 'DuplicatePointTolerance' : 0, 'ExtendOption' : 0, 'InputField' : '\"RN-60m\"', 'InputLayer' : 'file:///[path].csv?encoding=UTF-8&delimiter=,&xField=LON&yField=LAT&crs=epsg:4326', 'LabelDecimalPlaces' : -1, 'LabelTrimZeros' : False, 'LabelUnits' : '', 'MaxContourValue' : None, 'MinContourValue' : 0, 'NContour' : 400, 'OutputLayer' : 'C:/[path]/out.geojson' }
```

[image]

Comment: I think that using ContourInterval together with ContourLevels does not make sense but probably it is not a reason for your problem. You can still try.